# category subcategory tree issue javascript

Tags: javascript, tree

I have a tree.There are category and sub category as you can see from the image.I want that categories will have the lower line but subcategories will not .Can you please help me how i can do this? from this javascript?

[image]

Comment: *Format Code* button is your friend.

Comment: Sometimes does not work as expected at all

Comment: Diodeus: At least take my formatting so I can delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an attempt to format the above
Link here: http://destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/

```
/*--------------------------------------------------|
| dTree 2.05 | www.destroydrop.com/javascript/tree/ |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| Copyright (c) 2002-2003 Geir Landrö |
| |
| This script can be used freely as long as all |
| copyright messages are intact. |
| |
| Updated: 17.04.2003 |
|--------------------------------------------------*/
// Node object
function Node(id, pid, name, url, rel, target, icon, iconOpen, open) {
  this.id = id;
  this.pid = pid;
  this.name = name;
  this.url = url;
  this.rel = rel;
  this.target = target;
  this.icon = icon;
  this.iconOpen = iconOpen;
  this._io = open || false;
  this._is = false;
  this._ls = false;
  this._hc = false;
  this._ai = 0;
  this._p;
};
// Tree object
function dTree(objName) {
  this.config = {
      target                  : null,
      folderLinks         : true,
      useSelection        : true,
      useCookies          : true,
      useLines                : true,
      useIcons                : true,
      useStatusText       : false,
      closeSameLevel  : false,
      inOrder                 : false
  }
  this.icon = {
      root                : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      folder              : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/folder.gif',
      folderOpen          : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/folderopen.gif',
      node                : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/page.gif',
      empty               : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      line                : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      join                : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      joinBottom          : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      plus                : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      plusBottom          : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      minus               : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      minusBottom         : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      nlPlus              : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif',
      nlMinus             : 'http://wishberry.in/app/webroot/images/userend_images/img/empty.gif'
  };
  this.obj = objName;
  this.aNodes = [];
  this.aIndent = [];
  this.root = new Node(-1);
  this.selectedNode = null;
  this.selectedFound = false;
  this.completed = false;
};
// Adds a new node to the node array
dTree.prototype.add = function(id, pid, name, url, rel, target, icon, iconOpen, open) {
  this.aNodes[this.aNodes.length] = new Node(id, pid, name, url, rel, target, icon, iconOpen, open);
};
// Open/close all nodes
dTree.prototype.openAll = function() {
  this.oAll(true);
};
dTree.prototype.closeAll = function() {
  this.oAll(false);
};
// Outputs the tree to the page
dTree.prototype.toString = function() {
  var str = '<div class="dtree">\n';
  if (document.getElementById) {
      if (this.config.useCookies) this.selectedNode = this.getSelected();
      str += this.addNode(this.root);
  } else str += 'Browser not supported.';
  str += '</div>';
  if (!this.selectedFound) this.selectedNode = null;
  this.completed = true;
  return str;
};
// Creates the tree structure
dTree.prototype.addNode = function(pNode) {
  var str = '';
  var n=0;
  if (this.config.inOrder) n = pNode._ai;
  for (n; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
      if (this.aNodes[n].pid == pNode.id) {
          var cn = this.aNodes[n];
          cn._p = pNode;
          cn._ai = n;
          this.setCS(cn);
          if (!cn.target && this.config.target) cn.target = this.config.target;
          if (cn._hc && !cn._io && this.config.useCookies) cn._io = this.isOpen(cn.id);
          if (!this.config.folderLinks && cn._hc) cn.url = null;
          if (this.config.useSelection && cn.id == this.selectedNode && !this.selectedFound) {
                  cn._is = true;
                  this.selectedNode = n;
                  this.selectedFound = true;
          }
          str += this.node(cn, n);
          if (cn._ls) break;
      }
  }
  return str;
};
// Creates the node icon, url and text
dTree.prototype.node = function(node, nodeId) {
  var str = '<div class="dTreeNode">' + this.indent(node, nodeId);
  if (this.config.useIcons) {
      if (!node.icon) node.icon = (this.root.id == node.pid) ? this.icon.root : ((node._hc) ? this.icon.folder : this.icon.node);
      if (!node.iconOpen) node.iconOpen = (node._hc) ? this.icon.folderOpen : this.icon.node;
      if (this.root.id == node.pid) {
          node.icon = this.icon.root;
          node.iconOpen = this.icon.root;
      }
      str += '<img id="i' + this.obj + nodeId + '" src="' + ((node._io) ? node.iconOpen : node.icon) + '" alt="" />';
  }
  if (node.url) {
      str += '<a id="s' + this.obj + nodeId + '" class="' + ((this.config.useSelection) ? ((node._is ? 'nodeSel' : 'node')) : 'node') + '" href="' + node.url + '"';
      if (node.rel) str += ' rel="' + node.rel + '"';
      if (node.target) str += ' target="' + node.target + '"';
      if (this.config.useStatusText) str += ' onmouseover="window.status=\'' + node.name + '\';return true;" onmouseout="window.status=\'\';return true;" ';
      if (this.config.useSelection && ((node._hc && this.config.folderLinks) || !node._hc))
          str += ' onclick="javascript: ' + this.obj + '.s(' + nodeId + ');"';
      str += '>';
  }
  else if ((!this.config.folderLinks || !node.url) && node._hc && node.pid != this.root.id)
      str += '<a rel="' + node.rel + '" href="javascript: ' + this.obj + '.o(' + nodeId + ');" class="node">';
  str += node.name;
  if (node.url || ((!this.config.folderLinks || !node.url) && node._hc)) str += '</a>';
  str += '</div>';
  if (node._hc) {
      str += '<div id="d' + this.obj + nodeId + '" class="clip" style="display:' + ((this.root.id == node.pid || node._io) ? 'block' : 'none') + ';">';
      str += this.addNode(node);
      str += '</div>';
  }
  this.aIndent.pop();
  return str;
};
// Adds the empty and line icons
dTree.prototype.indent = function(node, nodeId) {
  var str = '';
  if (this.root.id != node.pid) {
      for (var n=0; n<this.aIndent.length; n++)
          str += '<img src="' + ( (this.aIndent[n] == 1 && this.config.useLines) ? this.icon.line : this.icon.empty ) + '" alt="" />';
      (node._ls) ? this.aIndent.push(0) : this.aIndent.push(1);
      if (node._hc) {
          str += '<a href="javascript: ' + this.obj + '.o(' + nodeId + ');"><img id="j' + this.obj + nodeId + '" src="';
          if (!this.config.useLines) str += (node._io) ? this.icon.nlMinus : this.icon.nlPlus;
          else str += ( (node._io) ? ((node._ls && this.config.useLines) ? this.icon.minusBottom : this.icon.minus) : ((node._ls && this.config.useLines) ? this.icon.plusBottom : this.icon.plus ) );
          str += '" alt="" /></a>';
      } else str += '<img src="' + ( (this.config.useLines) ? ((node._ls) ? this.icon.joinBottom : this.icon.join ) : this.icon.empty) + '" alt="" />';
  }
  return str;
};
// Checks if a node has any children and if it is the last sibling
dTree.prototype.setCS = function(node) {
  var lastId;
  for (var n=0; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
      if (this.aNodes[n].pid == node.id) node._hc = true;
      if (this.aNodes[n].pid == node.pid) lastId = this.aNodes[n].id;
  }
  //if (lastId==node.id) node._ls = true;
};
// Returns the selected node
dTree.prototype.getSelected = function() {
  var sn = this.getCookie('cs' + this.obj);
  return (sn) ? sn : null;
};
// Highlights the selected node
dTree.prototype.s = function(id) {
  if (!this.config.useSelection) return;
  var cn = this.aNodes[id];
  if (cn._hc && !this.config.folderLinks) return;
  if (this.selectedNode != id) {
      if (this.selectedNode || this.selectedNode==0) {
          eOld = document.getElementById("s" + this.obj + this.selectedNode);
          eOld.className = "node";
      }
      eNew = document.getElementById("s" + this.obj + id);
      eNew.className = "nodeSel";
      this.selectedNode = id;
      if (this.config.useCookies) this.setCookie('cs' + this.obj, cn.id);
  }
};
// Toggle Open or close
dTree.prototype.o = function(id) {
  var cn = this.aNodes[id];
  this.nodeStatus(!cn._io, id, cn._ls);
  cn._io = !cn._io;
  if (this.config.closeSameLevel) this.closeLevel(cn);
  if (this.config.useCookies) this.updateCookie();
};
// Open or close all nodes
dTree.prototype.oAll = function(status) {
  for (var n=0; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
      if (this.aNodes[n]._hc && this.aNodes[n].pid != this.root.id) {
          this.nodeStatus(status, n, this.aNodes[n]._ls)
          this.aNodes[n]._io = status;
      }
  }
  if (this.config.useCookies) this.updateCookie();
};
// Opens the tree to a specific node
dTree.prototype.openTo = function(nId, bSelect, bFirst) {
  if (!bFirst) {
      for (var n=0; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
          if (this.aNodes[n].id == nId) {
              nId=n;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  var cn=this.aNodes[nId];
  if (cn.pid==this.root.id || !cn._p) return;
  cn._io = true;
  cn._is = bSelect;
  if (this.completed && cn._hc) this.nodeStatus(true, cn._ai, cn._ls);
  if (this.completed && bSelect) this.s(cn._ai);
  else if (bSelect) this._sn=cn._ai;
  this.openTo(cn._p._ai, false, true);
};
// Closes all nodes on the same level as certain node
dTree.prototype.closeLevel = function(node) {
  for (var n=0; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
      if (this.aNodes[n].pid == node.pid && this.aNodes[n].id != node.id && this.aNodes[n]._hc) {
          this.nodeStatus(false, n, this.aNodes[n]._ls);
          this.aNodes[n]._io = false;
          this.closeAllChildren(this.aNodes[n]);
      }
  }
}
// Closes all children of a node
dTree.prototype.closeAllChildren = function(node) {
  for (var n=0; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
      if (this.aNodes[n].pid == node.id && this.aNodes[n]._hc) {
          if (this.aNodes[n]._io) this.nodeStatus(false, n, this.aNodes[n]._ls);
          this.aNodes[n]._io = false;
          this.closeAllChildren(this.aNodes[n]);      
      }
  }
}
// Change the status of a node(open or closed)
dTree.prototype.nodeStatus = function(status, id, bottom) {
  eDiv    = document.getElementById('d' + this.obj + id);
  eJoin   = document.getElementById('j' + this.obj + id);
  if (this.config.useIcons) {
      eIcon   = document.getElementById('i' + this.obj + id);
      eIcon.src = (status) ? this.aNodes[id].iconOpen : this.aNodes[id].icon;
  }
  eJoin.src = (this.config.useLines)?
  ((status)?((bottom)?this.icon.minusBottom:this.icon.minus):((bottom)?this.icon.plusBottom:this.icon.plus)):
  ((status)?this.icon.nlMinus:this.icon.nlPlus);
  eDiv.style.display = (status) ? 'block': 'none';
};
// [Cookie] Clears a cookie
dTree.prototype.clearCookie = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  this.setCookie('co'+this.obj, 'cookieValue', yesterday);
  this.setCookie('cs'+this.obj, 'cookieValue', yesterday);
};
// [Cookie] Sets value in a cookie
dTree.prototype.setCookie = function(cookieName, cookieValue, expires, path, domain, secure) {
  document.cookie =
      escape(cookieName) + '=' + escape(cookieValue)
      + (expires ? '; expires=' + expires.toGMTString() : '')
      + (path ? '; path=' + path : '')
      + (domain ? '; domain=' + domain : '')
      + (secure ? '; secure' : '');
  };
  // [Cookie] Gets a value from a cookie
  dTree.prototype.getCookie = function(cookieName) {
  var cookieValue = '';
  var posName = document.cookie.indexOf(escape(cookieName) + '=');
  if (posName != -1) {
      var posValue = posName + (escape(cookieName) + '=').length;
      var endPos = document.cookie.indexOf(';', posValue);
      if (endPos != -1) cookieValue = unescape(document.cookie.substring(posValue, endPos));
      else cookieValue = unescape(document.cookie.substring(posValue));
  }
  return (cookieValue);
};
// [Cookie] Returns ids of open nodes as a string
dTree.prototype.updateCookie = function() {
  var str = '';
  for (var n=0; n<this.aNodes.length; n++) {
      if (this.aNodes[n]._io && this.aNodes[n].pid != this.root.id) {
          if (str) str += '.';
          str += this.aNodes[n].id;
      }
  }
  this.setCookie('co' + this.obj, str);
};
// [Cookie] Checks if a node id is in a cookie
dTree.prototype.isOpen = function(id) {
  var aOpen = this.getCookie('co' + this.obj).split('.');
  for (var n=0; n<aOpen.length; n++)
      if (aOpen[n] == id) return true;
  return false;
};
// If Push and pop is not implemented by the browser
if (!Array.prototype.push) {
  Array.prototype.push = function array_push() {
      for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
          this[this.length]=arguments[i];
      return this.length;
  }
};
if (!Array.prototype.pop) {
  Array.prototype.pop = function array_pop() {
      lastElement = this[this.length-1];
      this.length = Math.max(this.length-1,0);
      return lastElement;
  }
};
```